# I am getting error while Failed building wheel for kivy command

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-wheel

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
  Failed to build kivy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml- 
  based projects
```

This is the source of speech to text file that is I try to install the owner of speech to text say you need to install these...

https://github.com/iAhsanJaved/Urdu2English

```
pip install SpeechRecognition kivy googletrans
```

but while I execute the command, it then takes too much time and then the error show on my screen. Please help,

[image]

Comment: pip install pyproject-toml should solve you problem.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: error shows `"portaudo.h" file not found`  - and `portaudio.h` is C/C++ header file and this can means you have to install `portaudio` source code or at least header files. On Linux headers files usually are in packages with suffix `-dev`. On my Linux I used `apt search portaudio` and found `portaudio19-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Error shows

```
"portaudio.h" file not found
```

and this is main problem.

It seems `SpeechRecognition` needs Python module `pyaudio` which needs C/C++ library `portaudio` and its C/C++ headers `portaudio.h` to correctly compile C/C++ code in `pyaudio`.

`portaudio` is not Python module so you can't install it with `pip` but with tools like `apt` on `Linux Mint/Ubuntu` or probably `brew` on `Mac`.

I use Linux Mint.

On Linux Mint packages with headers usuall have suffix `-dev` (because they are needed to `develop` code) and I can find them with

```
apt search portaudio
```

which gives me `libportaudio2` and `portaudio19-dev` so I can install

```
apt install libportaudio2 portaudio19-dev
```

and this should resolve this problem.